# Control Instructions in C

Tags: c

I am not understanding for loop statement and expression following it. Please do help me understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   int y = 1;
   for( ; y ; printf("%d %d\n",x,y))
       y = x++ <= 5;
   return 0;
}
```

And the output I got

```
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 0
```

Comment: +1 im not clear why the downvotes, the code appears to be deliberately convoluted and the op is asking for help understanding what its doing, a valid question that might help many beginners. It is not the OP's code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`y = x++ <= 5;`  ==> `y = (x++ <= 5);`  ==> first compare `x` with `5` to check whether `x`  is small then or equals to `5` or not. Result of `(x++ <= 5)` is either `1`, `0` assigned to `y`,

As `x` becomes > `5`, `(x++ <= 5)` becomes `0` so `y = 0` and condition `false` and loop break,

Comment: @Sandeep you may like to check: [What is the name of this operator: “`-->`”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

Comment: @sjas may be not as I could understand Sandeep's (OP) main confusion was expression `y = x++ <= 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your variables:

```
int x = 1; int y = 1;
```

There are `3` statements for the `for loop`: -1.  Initialize, 2.  Condition, 3. Iteration:increment/decrement
In your case, you did not provide the initialize condition, however, you have the part of condition and incrementation. I do not think your for loop is used in the correct way.

You should swap the part of incrementation with your body like this:

```
for(; y; y = x++ <= 5;)
   printf("%d %d\n", x, y)
```

First, you check whether the condition is true or not, `y` is true or not. Then, you print `x` and `y` out. Then, the part of incrementation is executed, `x++ <= 5` or not. The result is assigned to `y`. It does so until your condition is false, `y` == `false`.

**NOTE:** For the good programming, you should enclose your body with a curly braces.

Comment: Good practice is also keep space after `;` and `,` and expression `a<=b;` should be written like `a <= b`.  I given some formatting to your answer to make it readable. btw good answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Basically the for syntax is:
for(StartCondition; Test; PostLoopOperation) DoWhileTestPasses;

In this case:

```
StartCondition == None
Test == (y != 0)
PostLoopOperation == do some printing 
DoWhileTestPasses == set y to zero if x > 5 otherwise to non-zero THEN increment x.
```

Which is all rather bad practice because it is confusing.

Would be better written as:

```
int x=0;
int y=0;
for(y=0; y = (x <= 6); x++)
{
    printff("%d %d\n",x,y);
}
return(0);
```

Comment: In your last point, it appears to me, that since its a postfix increment, hence increment x must come after the word otherwise :-)

Comment: Correct @nIcEcOw - solution adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

In `y = x++ <= 5;`, `y` stores the value that is output by the condition `x++ <= 5` (here `x++` is post increment). If the condition is true then `y = 1` else `y = 0`.

```
for( ; y ; printf("%d %d\n",x,y))
```

In the for loop you are printing the values of `x` and `y` after executing the for loop body.

Answer (score 0):

similar to this

```
   int x = 1;
   for( int y = 1; y!=0 ; )
   {
       if (x++ <= 5)
       {
          y = 1;
       } 
       else
       {
          y = 0;
       }
       printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this slightly transformed (but functionally equal) code will help:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
while (y) {
   y = (x <= 5);
   x = x + 1;
   printf("%d %d\n", x, y)
}
```